# Recommendations of websites or services for saving any audio of Chinese sentence

Tags: pronunciation, learning

Can I save an audio of Baidu Translate?

I can save an audio of Google Translate using the following URL.

https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&tl=zh-CN&q=HERE_COMES_A_CHINESE_SENTENCE

> [妈妈 要 去 超市。](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Directional_verbs_%22lai%22_and_%22qu%22)
>
> Māma yào qù chāoshì
>
> Mom will go to the supermarket.

The pronunciation of the sentence is done in [this way](https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&tl=zh-CN&q=%E5%A6%88%E5%A6%88%E8%A6%81%E5%8E%BB%E8%B6%85%E5%B8%82%E3%80%82) via Google translate.

The last **shì** is not correctly pronounced.

However Baidu Translate seems [pronounce it correctly](https://fanyi.baidu.com/#zh/en/%E5%A6%88%E5%A6%88%20%E8%A6%81%20%E5%8E%BB%20%E8%B6%85%E5%B8%82%E3%80%82) so I want to save an audio of a Chinese sentence using Baidu translate. Is it possible?

Or is there any alternative(s) about it?

BTW I heavily using google chrome so I am not get accustomed with Firefox AddOns...

Comment: [Microsoft Edge Read Aloud](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/grv8ey/psa_%E6%88%91%E5%8B%92%E4%B8%AA%E5%8E%BBmicrosoft_edge_read_aloud_function_is_the/) is supposed to be good at text-to-speech.  And you can record sounds your browser is playing with extensions such as [Audio to MP3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/audio-to-mp3/).

Comment: I've been installing Edge on my computer now :D

Comment: @Becky李蓓 I can't locate a button of "Read aloud"...